# Verify Firebase idToken via Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase for the first time and am unable to verify that a user is authenticated from the Firebase idToken.

I've attempted to use Google App Engine's example in flask: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes.

I've also tried using python libraries mentioned by Firebase here: https://jwt.io/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply to identify a user you have to send the token that generates javascript as a header in the request to the server

```
Authorization:key=eyJhbGc .... ZgeFONFh7HgQ    
id_token = request.headers['Authorization'].split('=').pop()
```

Once you have that token with the library google.oauth2.id_token will ask for the UID of that generated token

```
claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(id_token, HTTP_REQUEST)
If not claims:
         Return 'Unauthorized', 401
UID = claims['sub']
```

Already with that UID is like your PK in any DB that you use

Comment: That makes sense and is very similar to the google flask example I linked to however I keep getting this error: "from google.appengine.ext import ndb
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext"

Comment: =>1. Install Gcloud. =>2. gcloud components install app-engine-python =>3. run dev server with "$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml" don't use Windows because dosen't work

Comment: Thanks! Had to setup everything on my mac and it finally worked after running 'pip install <dependency> -t lib/' for google-auth==0.7.0, requests==2.13.0, requests-toolbelt==0.7.1

Comment: where does HTTP_REQUEST come from?